# Is $Q( (1 + \frac{1}{2})^{2}, (1 + \frac{1}{3})^{3}, (1 + \frac{1}{4})^4, \ldots )$ an algebraic extension of $Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Each of $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ is in $Q$, but is the given extension algebraic? Is the extension just equal to $Q$?

Comment: Yes and yes. ${}$

Comment: @Wojowu Ok and I suppose that is because of the general idea that if $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ are each algebraic over $F$, then $F(a_1, a_2, \ldots )$ is an algebraic extension of $F$?

Comment: That's correct. But in this case it's even simpler: $\mathbb Q((1+1/2)^2,\dots)$ is, by definition, the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q$ and $(1+1/2)^2,\dots$. Since $\mathbb Q$ already contains those numbers, the extension is just $\mathbb Q$, and $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Q$ is trivially algebraic.

Comment: @Wojowu Gotcha. More generally now, I am convinced that if $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are algebraic over $F$, then $F(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ is algebraic, but am having trouble convincing myself that this extends to the countably infinite case.

Comment: Also, is it true for arbitrary collections of algebraic elements? That is, if $A$ is a (not necessarily countable) collection of elements each algebraic over a field $F$, is the smallest field containing $F$ and each element of $A$ necessarily an algebraic extension?

Comment: What is the definition of an algebraic extension? It’s that each element of the extension is algebraic. Since your $\Bbb Q(a_1,a_2,\cdots)$ is the union of the finitely-generated subfields, all is well.

Comment: @Lubin Ah thank you, I think I have it now. I will formalize things and write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Wojowu notes, my specified extension is easily seen to be equal to $Q$ and thus an algebraic extension of $Q$. What follows is a generalization of concepts discussed in the comments above.

Suppose $A$ is a set of elements algebraic over a field $F$. I show that $F(A)$, the smallest field which contains $F$ and $A$ is an algebraic extension of $F$, by showing that $F(A) = \bigcup_{a \in A} F(a)$, and then showing that $\bigcup_{a \in A} F(a)$ is algebraic.

Let $K = \bigcup_{a \in A} F(a)$. If $x \in K$, then $x \in F(a)$ for some $a \in A$, so $x \in F(A)$ and $K \subseteq F(A)$.

Since $F \subseteq K$ and $a \in K$ for each $a \in A$, we have $F(A) \subseteq K$ by minimality. So $K = F(A)$, and K is algebraic because the union of algebraic extensions is an algebraic extension.